# How to center align the image in Google chrome which is already center aligned in mozilla firefox?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, firefox

I'm displaying an image after clicking on the hyperlink. When I show the image in mozilla firefox it is center aligned but when I display the same image in Google chrome it is left aligned. I'm not understanding why this is happening. For your reference I'm giving below the HTML code along with the screenshots in mozilla firefox as well as Google chrome.

HTML code is as follows:

```
<a style="font-size:17px;" href="Annual Gathering 2014.jpg"><strong><font color="42515a">ANNUAL GATHERING 2014 ( Click to view the detail schedule)</font></strong></a>
```

The screen shot in Mozilla Firefox is as follows:
[image]

The screen shot in Google Chrome is as follows:
[image]

Thanks for understanding my issue. Waiting for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the different browser's individual default behaviour for displaying images, as you have linked straight to the image rather than embedding the image in a HTML page.

If you do decide to embed it in a HTML page and link to the page rather than the image, then you have control as to how the image will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

use this to center an image in its parent element

```
img{
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```